# Most suitable approachs for retrieving Master and Detail Tables in MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, view

In order to populate Dropdownlists, showing the details rather than id on Gridviews (showing City name instead of Birt city id), etc., sometimes we need to retrieve data at the same time from Master (for ex. **Student**) and Detail (for ex. **City**) tables. Could you suggest me which scenarios below is the most suitable? In addition to this I would be appreciated if you suggest other approaches provided that using Entity Framework.

1) I retrieve data from Entity tables and I use relations between master and detail tables. But in that case I need to define these relations on my DbContext and I have to populate dropdownlists by methods. But for displaying data I need to define another methods or etc. For this reason actually I do not like this approach. What do you think for this?

2) Instead of this I can use ModelView as I had used before. But, I think it is not good idea return more tables instead of one table lots of times. In addition to this, I think I need a extra definition for dropdownlist for example in an htl helper. I think it is also not handy.

3) As it is used commonly, I think getting data from entity views (database view) instead of entity table seems to be very useful. With the help of this approach, I can retrieve data from 2 tables and I can easily show this data on dropdownlists and grids without an extra effort. What do you think?

a) On the other hand, if I use a view entity instead of table entity, how can I save this entity to the database (normally I return table entity for creating/editing).

b) If this method is good, in that case I think I need extra entity definitions for the related database views in addition to the tables. For example I have Student, City entities now. But for the database View I need another 3rd entity. Could you give me a usage example for this approach?
BR.

Comment: Sorry I am a little confused as to what you are trying to accomplish. Are you simply populating drop down lists, or master / details grid views?

Comment: I do not mean only populating Dropdownlists. I also wanted to display data on grid. While doing this, I wanted to be clarified about retrieving the data from database View rather than one table so that I can also use display members besides value members.